# Expandable Objects - Managed C++

Tags: c++-cli, custom-controls

I try to develop custom control in managed c++, My custom cuntrol inherits from the Control class, As part of it i want to add custom properties to my custom control, to do that i created a class called ControlStyle, this class contains some properties like: colors, font etc.

Now i want to make a property of type ControlStyle in the CustomControl class, I'll explain myself: I want a property of type ControlStyle that will shown with the "+" sign in the properties window (called expandable properties),  in the class CustomControl. so i did it, the problem is: that i drag and drop the custom control to a form and modify the values of the ControlStyle properties, and when i execute the application i see that any value of the ControlStyle properties that were changed by the user at the design time - not saved, and waht i get at runtime is the initial value of the ControlStyle properties, I understand that i'm not so clear, so lets talk code:

My ControlStyle class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeid(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public ref class ControlStyle
{
     // private variables
     private: System::Drawing::Font^ font;
     private: Color backColor1 = Color::Blue;
     private: Color backColor2 = Color::Red;

     // constructor
     public: ControlStyle::ControlStyle()
     {   
         font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 12);
     }

     // properties
     public: property Color BackColor1
     {
         Color get() { retun backColor1; }
         void set(Color value) { backColor1 = value; }
     }

     public: property Color BackColor2
     {
         Color get() { retun backColor2; }
         void set(Color value) { backColor2 = value; }
     }

     public: virtual property System::Drawing::Font^ Font
     {
         virtual System::Drawing::Font^ get() override { return font; }
         virtual void set(System::Drawing::Font^ value) override
         { font = value; }
     }
}
```

My CustomControl class:

```
public ref class CustomControl : public System::Windows::Forms::Control
{ 
    // private variables
    private: ControlStyle^ controlStyle;

    // constructor
    public: CustomControl::CustomControl()
    {
        controlStyle = gcnew ControlStyle();
    }

    // properties
    public: property ControlStyle^ Style
    {
        ControlStyle^ get() { return controlStyle; }            
    }

    // methods like paint etc.
}
```

When i use the custom control on a form, (i see the first values of the ControlStyle properties like the initialization of them in the ControlStyle class), and i modify the values of the ControlStyle properties (Note: i modify the values of ControlStyle properties **not by code**, but **manually** by the properties window and i see the changes on the control - it works well), for example:

```
customControl1->Style->BackColor1 = Color::Green;
```

When i execute the program i see (at runtime) that the value of the customControl1->Style->BackColor1 property is Color::Blue that is the value of it's initial definition, and not Color::Green - which is the value that i put at design time.

To solve the issue i wrote the values that the customControl1->Style->BackColor1 property gets by the user at design time to a file and read it back when the DesignMode property change it's value to false, and additional attempts like this - and nothing...

I saw blogs says that it problem of serialization.

also applying the SerializableAttribute to the classes - does not work.

I think the reason for this problem is the initialization of the controlStyle variable in the CustomControl's constructor, i.e:

```
controlStyle = gcnew ControlStyle();
```

But this initialization must to be done for the control's function.

I will be very grateful for any help. Thanks alot!!

Comment: You'd have to add the [Serializable] attribute so it can be stored.  This is not wise, add the properties to the control class instead.

Comment: I want to create expandable properties, this is just an example. expandable properties are shown with the "+" sign in the properties window, example of expandable properties: Size, Font, Location, etc.